# Can Facebook users on a facebook app be anonymous?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create an app for closeted and questioning youth on facebook, and an important feature would be the ability to be anonymous on the app. I've been trying to find out if people can be anonymous on facebook, but this sounds like it's not allowed. Could facebook users make a new user account within a facebook app to protect their identity?

Thanks,
Colby

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot create a new facebook account from facebook app. And facebook has nothing to do with making a user anonymous, if user has given your application required permissions then you can have all the information about user, its up to you either you want to make that user an "Anonymous user" or show his profile pic/information.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- In *App Settings* > *Auth Dialog* there is the setting **Default
  Activity Privacy** which you should set to **Only Me**.
- When a user authorizes your app store as little information as is
  necessary, and prominently display your privacy policy explaining
  what type of information you store, why, and how you will never
  share it with anyone.
- *(optional)* Store userids in your database as md5 hashes so that even if someone gains access to that database, they won't know who
  the users are.